# Append an Element to another Element Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append the imgclone to the another div called **fa-shopping-bag**  however the append doesn't work and what happens is it overlaps the screens

```
$('.add').on('click', function () {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
    var cart  = $('.fa-shopping-bag');
    var imgtodrag = $('#product-images > div > ul.slides > li.flex-active-slide > img:nth-child(1)');
    if (imgtodrag) {
        var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
            .offset({
                top: imgtodrag.offset().top + 250,
                left: imgtodrag.offset().left
            })
            .css({
                'opacity': '0.5',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'height': '150px',
                'width': '150px',
                'z-index': '100'
            })
            .appendTo($('.fa-shopping-bag'))
            .animate({

                'top': 0,
                'right': 0,
                'width': 50,
                'height': 50
            }, 3000, 'easeInOutExpo');


        imgclone.animate({
            'width': 0,
            'height': 0
        }, function () {
            $(this).detach()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: it is really hard to tell what are you trying to do here, could you please come up with a small jsfiddle example reflecting your problem? please mind that knowing your HTML structure and CSS styles might help answering the question

Comment: as a suggestion, it might be that when you create a clone and put it in the different position, it has different position context, i.e. different parent having  `position: absolute` or `position: relative`.

Comment: on a side note: your code is really heavy for the browser, please consider reducing the amount of animations and inline element lookups

Comment: there is no css on that

Comment: There's nothing overtly wrong with the code. Sometimes you just have to work at these CSS/animation things before you get to where you want to be.